# What's the French equivalent for “stick out like a sore thumb”?

Tags: traduction, expressions, anglais

In English, if something is egregiously out of place, it can be said that it is “sticking out like a sore thumb”.  Example:

> I was so bad at playing football and they were all professionals; I stuck out like a sore thumb!

What's an equivalent way of conveying this phrase in French?

---

Résumé : Y a-t-il un verbe ou une expression française qui veut dire que quelque chose n'est vraiment pas à sa place, de manière bien visible ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Je propose :

- *Détonner*
- *Faire tache* (no circumflex!)
- *Jurer dans le décor*
- *Se voir comme le nez au milieu de la figure*.

Comment: Not to mention "visible comme une mouche dans un verre de lait" - conspicuous as a fly in a glass of milk. Yuk!

Comment: "Jurer dans le décor"? Jamais entendu.

Comment: @Knu Moi si, pas si rarement...

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps something like *faire tache* (or *faire tache dans le paysage*) or *paraître déplacé*.

Comment: _faire tâche_ may be followed by _dans le paysage_.

Comment: No circumflex on *tache*, please!

Comment: Indeed, may my iniquity be visited upon me and my children unto the third and fourth generation.

Answer (score 4):

On peut aussi dire que quelque chose est « grand comme une maison » ou « gros comme une maison ».

Comment: Plutôt grand comme une *maison* (je ne peut pas corriger, modification trop petite)

Comment: Plutôt « je ne peux pas corriger ». :)

Comment: Argh ! Honte à moi (bouhhh, mais bon c'était tard le soir, enfin je crois...). Pis maintenant c'est maison*n* ?!

Comment: On dit plutôt *gros* comme une maison.

Answer (score 2):

If it is out of place in a positive manner, you can say "sortir du lot".